# Floating images in Github Readme

Tags: image, github, markdown, floating

How would I go about doing this? Putting the following code into the
[Markdown generator](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/dingus)
gives me the desired output

```
<div style="float: left"><img src="http://ompldr.org/vaDU5NQ/scrotter.png"/>
</div>
I'm trying not to, kid. Don't act so surprised, Your Highness. You weren't
on any mercy mission this time. Several transmissions were beamed to this
ship by Rebel spies. I want to know what happened to the plans they sent
you. Kid, I've flown from one side of this galaxy to the other.

I've seen a lot of strange stuff, but I've never seen anything to make me
believe there's one all-powerful Force controlling everything.
```

However, adding this code to my README.md file makes it an inline image instead
of floating.

How could I work around this? Is it a Github bug?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

I know this thread's old, but for anyone interested, you can use `<img align="left" src="img.jpg">` and `<img align="right" src="img.jpg">` to float images on GitHub.

Comment: It works, but is old-style HTML (not supported in HTML5). Unfortunately, there is no way to customize image floating that conforms to both HTML5 and GFM at the same time.

Comment: I don't think Markdown in a GitHub ReadMe needs to validate as HTML5. It's for documenting a code repository; not for being a website.

Comment: is there a `float: clear` equivalent, too?

Comment: @MartinRauscher I don't think so.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is a security issue with GitHub. My understanding is they strip all HTML attributes such as `style` with the execption of perhaps `href`.

Comment: Old question but I ended up using gh-pages instead of my readme file, because it's just a much better way of doing things - gh-pages isn't restricted by this, and behaves like a normal html page.